# Datetimepicker in form not transferring date

Tags: php, jquery, opencart, datetimepicker

At the backend of my opencart e-commerce package, there is the  possibility to insert vouchers for customers. However, there is standard no possibility to set a start and end date (1 year later) for the voucher. Therefore I have adapted the voucher.tpl template to include this possibility. I have implemented this completely identical as for the coupon.tpl where there is the possibility to enter a start date and end date.

The input field for the start date and end date is using the datetimepicker script. The datepicker is showing up correctly when I click the calendar button (see image 1) and the date is showing up.

[image: image1]

The dates are used in a form, but unfortunately the data seem not be transferred with the form when the save button is clicked. I see no difference with the coupon.tpl page where everything is working properly. I spent already many hours in founding the error but did not succeed yet. Could somebody help me on my way? 
Thanks,
SabKo

The voucher.tpl has the following code:

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="page-header">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="pull-right">
       <button type="submit" form="form-voucher" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
       <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a>
     </div>
     <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
     <ul class="breadcrumb">
       <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
       <?php } ?>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
   </div>
   <?php } ?>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
       <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_form; ?></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
       <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-voucher" class="form-horizontal">
         <div class="tab-content">
           <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-general">
             <div class="form-group required">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-code"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $help_code; ?>"><?php echo $entry_code; ?></span>
               </label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <input type="text" name="code" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_code; ?>" id="input-code" class="form-control" />
                 <?php if ($error_code) { ?>
                 <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_code; ?></div>
                 <?php } ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group required">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-from-name"><?php echo $entry_from_name; ?>
               </label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <input type="text" name="from_name" value="<?php echo $from_name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_from_name; ?>" id="input-from-name" class="form-control" />
                 <?php if ($error_from_name) { ?>
                 <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_from_name; ?></div>
                 <?php } ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group required">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-to-name"><?php echo $entry_to_name; ?></label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <input type="text" name="to_name" value="<?php echo $to_name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_to_name; ?>" id="input-to-name" class="form-control" />
                 <?php if ($error_to_name) { ?>
                 <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_to_name; ?></div>
                 <?php } ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-amount"><?php echo $entry_amount; ?></label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_amount; ?>" id="input-amount" class="form-control" />
                 <?php if ($error_amount) { ?>
                 <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_amount; ?></div>
                 <?php } ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-date-start"><?php echo $entry_date_start; ?></label>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <div class="input-group date">
                   <input type="text" name="date_start" value="<?php echo $date_start; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_start; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" id="input-date-start" class="form-control" />
                   <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                   </span></div>
               </div>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-date-end"><?php echo $entry_date_end; ?></label>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <div class="input-group date">
                   <input type="text" name="date_end" value="<?php echo $date_end; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date_end; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" id="input-date-end" class="form-control" />
                   <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                   </span></div>
               </div>
             </div>
           <?php if ($voucher_id) { ?>
           <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-history">
             <div id="history"></div>
           </div>
           <?php } ?>
         </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
   $('.date').datetimepicker({
   pickTime: false
  });
  //--></script>
</div>
```

The controller page has the following code, so should be able to read the input of the dates:

```
    if (isset($this->request->post['date_start'])) {
        $data['date_start'] = $this->request->post['date_start'];
    } elseif (!empty($voucher_info)) {
        $data['date_start'] = ($voucher_info['date_start'] != '0000-00-00' ? $voucher_info['date_start'] : '');
    } else {
        $data['date_start'] = date('Y-m-d', time());
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['date_end'])) {
        $data['date_end'] = $this->request->post['date_end'];
    } elseif (!empty($voucher_info)) {
        $data['date_end'] = ($voucher_info['date_end'] != '0000-00-00' ? $voucher_info['date_end'] : '');
    } else {
        $data['date_end'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));
    }
```

Comment: I am not familiar with opencart but You can try `var_dump($_POST);` and check if there is date_start and date_end fields.

Comment: The date_start and date_end fields are empty when the form is submitted but I have no idea why. Regards SabKo

Comment: Ok then this code is always executed `$data['date_start'] = $this->request->post['date_start'];`. So it must be something wrong with javascript. Please try to type in console: `$('#form-voucher').serialize()` and see if there are date inputs with correct data

Comment: Also which datetime picker plugin do You use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initialize your datetime picker on div with class .date but you have to initialize it on inputs with their classes or ids.

replace this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
   $('.date').datetimepicker({
   pickTime: false
  });
  //--></script>
```

with this one:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
 $('#input-date-start').datetimepicker({
   pickTime: false
  });
   $('#input-date-end').datetimepicker({
   pickTime: false
  });
  //--></script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this possibility, but still not working. The date_start and date_end fields are still empty when submitted. Also, the calender is only showing now when I click in the date input field. It is not working anymore when I click on the calendar symbol button.

Comment: After you pick the start date try to run in your browser console the following code:
$('#input-date-start').val();
if there will be some value than the problem is with form submit.

Comment: Also check the form action parameter whether it points to correct opencart controller and method

Comment: Hello Kaly4ik, I have got it working now. Essentially, there was an error in my controller page (error checking code). Your example code is working, as is the original code. Thanks for the support

Comment: @SanKo , how you call at the front the data because I try can but be empty.